# How to prevent a component to render on first run

Tags: react-native

I'm building an app in react native, and need to prevent one of the component to render on the first run.

If I set a boolean variable, the value will keep changing each next time the component should render.

```
const [firstRun, setFirstRun] = useState(true)

    <View >
          {(firstRun != true) (
          <p> Show component! </p>
          )
          setFirstRun(false);
          }
    </View>
```

EDIT: I try this way, in this case it could work, but i receive console error. How can i limit the setState to run just 1 time?

```
    firstRun = 0;
    
        <View >
           {(this.firstRun != 0) &&
            <View >
            <p> something </p>
            </View >
           {this.setState({ firstRun: this.state.firstRun + 1 })}
        </View>
```

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: Do you mean - you want the system to remember that the first run has been made, even if your smart phone killed the app and restart the app it will remember ? (or just when you switch screens ? --- assuming your app has multiple screens )

Comment: Open App - (first run > don't render component) - click button - render component

If you kill the app, the above line start again

Comment: Please also post the codes on your button click to see what you are attempting. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the thread, sorry for my bad english, maybe now is more clear what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you put the above view in "componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate" block ? (or put the view in a function which will be triggered by "componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate" ????

Comment: No, i'm just starting and don't know how those functions works, could you give me a hint?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the necessary data (e.g. display the word 'ken') in a separate function and then use the state to determine what to display in that function.

1. set state =0 for "ken1" in constructor
2. click a button that will update the state to 1
3. the function kentest will display null if ken1=0 and ken1 <> 0, so clicking the button can accomplish what you want (initially not display anything, but after first-run, will display)

Here is a working example:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";

export default class test extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ken1: 0,
    };
  }

  kentest() {
    if (this.state.ken1 == 0) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return "ken";
    }
  }

  increasecount() {
    this.setState({ ken1: 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.kentest()}
        <Text> something </Text>
        <Button title="Click" onPress={() => this.increasecount()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You may also view the result here:
https://snack.expo.io/tjzplrbgx